# activate Button from added CCScene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am adding a new layer to a scene. The new layer is loaded from a ccb file which includes buttons:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]; //pauses current scene
CCScene *pauseMenue = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Pause"];
pauseMenue.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
pauseMenue.position= ccp(0.5,0.5);
[self addChild:pauseMenue]; //adds the pause Layer
```

How do I get the buttons to work? Using the CCControl Selector doesn't seem to work…

-Pause.ccb doesn't consists of further ccb files.

-Pause.ccb has its custom class in which I tried to implement the selectors.

Comment: More info please. How did you set up the code connection in SpriteBuilder? Does Pause.ccb consist of multiple CCBs? Does Pause.ccb have a custom class where you implemented the button selectors?

Comment: no idea what the problem is?